# Music: Practice and Theory email digest?

Tags: feature-request

Is there an email digest for this site yet like many of the other Stack Exchange sites? It's my favorite way to see the questions from the past week and to see some unanswered questions that need attention.

Answer (score 6):

It already exists. If you check http://stackexchange.com/newsletters, it's featured under "Arts": http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=music.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MatthewRead: Nice. I was looking for a specific link, but didn't manage to dig it up...